# Multiple middleware in next.jsMultiple middleware in next.js

Tags: next.js, clerk, next-intl

The structure of my files:
app -> [locale] -> (admin) [dashboard] page.js - (shop) page.js

I want to use clerk only for dashboard and its subpages and next-intl for all pages. I found the following code in clerk docs but it applies authentication to all pages.

```
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";

const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware({
  locales: ["en", "fa"],
  defaultLocale: "fa",
});

export default authMiddleware({
  beforeAuth: (req) => {
    return intlMiddleware(req);
  },

  publicRoutes: ["/", "/:locale/sign-in"],
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};
```

I tried to use this [way](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/nested-middleware) but I don't understand how to merge these two solutions together

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended up here. I think the solution below is on the right track.

In my case, I'm trying to add locale to the path if it's missing, but also protect most routes - which looks like it might be similar to what you're doing. I used afterAuth and publicRoutes:

```
export default authMiddleware({
  afterAuth: (auth, req, evt) => {
    if (auth.userId || auth.isPublicRoute) {
      return localeMiddleware(req);
    }
    // redirect unauthenticated users to about, but keep the locale
    // if there is one
    const locale = getLocaleOrDefault(req)
    req.nextUrl.pathname = `/${locale}/about`
    return Response.redirect(req.nextUrl) 
  },
  publicRoutes: [
    "/en/about",
    "/es/about",
    "/about/"
  ]
});

export const config = {
      matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};
```

I pretty new to nextjs / clerk so this might not be the best approach.